# VS Code - Disable workspace settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the company I work in, someone had an idea to create workspace related color theme settings to better distinguish which project is currently active (pointless IMO). The problem is that I don't see any way to disable these settings. According to the documentation, workspace settings override user settings.

Does anyone have any idea or sugjestion on how I can overcome this issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Communicate with said "someone", explain the problem.

Comment: You already have three settings tiers available (app, user and workspace). There isn't a fourth if that's what you're asking. How exactly do you distribute workspace settings? If you do so by committing `.vscode\settings.json` to version control, anything you customise with create conflicts with the rest of the team.

Comment: I have a setting that works for most on the project, but not for me. I would love to be able to override it on my machine. It's my machine darn it!

Answer (score 0):

For most settings you may able to patch their configuration scope to application level ([doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration), [example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/e2eb2ec0d759173393595211f645fecccad1b6c2/src/vs/workbench/contrib/experiments/browser/experiments.contribution.ts#L30)), then their workspace or language-specific settings will be ignored.

You can modify the source and build your own vscode, or patch `workbench.desktop.main.js`: find pattern `"setting.name":{description:...,type:...}`, add `,scope:1` before `}`
(1=ConfigurationScope.APPLICATION)